# How to prove that the metric $d=\sup \lbrace d_i(x_i,y_i) \rbrace$ satisfy the triangle inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, supremum-and-infimum

Let $(X_i
, d_i), i ∈ \Bbb N$, be a collection of metric spaces.  Here $x = (x_1, . . . , x_n)$ and $y = (y_1, . . . , y_n)$ are
elements of $\prod_{i \in \Bbb N} X_i.$

Define the metric $d(x,y)=\sup \lbrace d_i(x_i,y_i) \rbrace$ on the infinite product $\prod_{i \in \Bbb N} X_i.$

My question is how to prove that the metric $d(x,y)=\sup \lbrace d_i(x_i,y_i) \rbrace$ satisfy the triangle inequality? Can I ask for someone's help? Thanks so much.

Comment: So does one allow $\infty$ as a possible value of $d(x,y)$ when the sup is not finite?

Comment: In your example of $x,y$ each one has only $n$ coordinates, making it seem they lie in a *finite* product, not an infinite product over $i \in \mathbb{N}.$

Comment: @coffeemath I realized there might be a problem here. I asked a new one:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2201440/prove-that-beginaligndx-y-sum-i-in-mathbbn-a-i-fracd-ix-i-y-i1.

Answer (score 0):

For every $i$ we have $d_i(x_i,x_i)+d_i(y_i,y_i) \ge d_i(x_i+y_i,x_i+y_i)$ because metric space $X_i,d_i$ satisfies triangle inequality.

Suppose that : $\sup \lbrace d_i(x_i,x_i) \rbrace +\sup \lbrace d_i(y_i,y_i)  \rbrace  \lt \sup \lbrace d_i(x_i+y_i,x_i+y_i)  \rbrace $. That would mean that for some $i$ : $  d_i(x_i,x_i)   +  d_i(y_i,y_i)    \lt  d_i(x_i+y_i,x_i+y_i)   $. This contradicts with the fact that the triangle inequality is valid in all spaces $X_i$ individually.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I just realized there might be a problem here because $sup$ cannot be infinite. So I asked a new question here:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2201440/prove-that-beginaligndx-y-sum-i-in-mathbbn-a-i-fracd-ix-i-y-i1